# Why doesn't equating two sums in a conditional evaluate to true?

Tags: c

I am trying to return the index where the sum of the left hand side is equal to the right hand side. But I get a default of -1. Why doesn't the conditional evaluate to true?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_even_index(const int *values, int length)
{
  int count = 0;
  int sumL = 0;
  int sumR = 0;

  while(count < length)
  {
    sumR += values[count];
    count++;
  }
  count = 0;

  while(count < length)
  {
    sumL += values[count];
    sumR -= values[count];
    printf("sumL = %d\n", sumL);
    printf("sumR = %d\n", sumR);
    if(sumL == sumR)//why doesn't this condition work?
    {
      return count;
    }

    count++;
  }

  return -1;
}

int main (void)
{

  int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,3,2,1 };
  printf("%d\n", (find_even_index(arr, 7)));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output do you get from your `printf` statements?  Anyway, it's because your array has an odd number of elements and is symmetrical, so it's giving you the right answer :) .  Try `{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 }`.  Voting to close as a typo, but that's no reflection on you!  We all do things like that sometimes :D .

Comment: The error might have been easier to spot with a single `printf("sumL = %d; sumR = %d\n", sumL, sumR);`.  That way you can tell which `sumL` value lines up with which `sumR` value more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are comparing the numbers after adding and subtracting both of them. So in the moment they are about to be the same:

```
sumL = 6; sumR = 10
```

You then sum 4 to sumL and subtract 4 to sumR:

```
sumL = 10; sumR = 6
```

And then you compare and get different values. You have to check in between the operations.